# How to use devtools to open links in new tab in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, webautomation

How do I properly use devtools to open links in a new tab, wait for page to load, and then get attributes of elements in the new tab, one by one, in a for loop?

I know this is trivial but I can't make it work, and I Googled nothing relevant.

Minimal reproducible example:

I generated 3 files with exactly 1 MiB of random data each, they are named mb1, mb2 and mb3. I uploaded them to zippyshare and them put the links to filecrypt.

SHA256:

```
mb1 DF69A9680EC23D9715825C5E9FE24AB42A7FACF0B8BD3F6FEE12135927A91E84
mb2 CE3C56E97119D98FBCCD916A0301F529DBC16B6766B247FFCA222BDE24F9603E
mb3 7B0BF694C39E0CE28A9C8D0ADED7D8E9A63AB417ABD1733A22369EC63A380951
```

[Filecrypt link](https://filecrypt.cc/Container/CE67E63AF7.html)

On that page you will see three buttons that link to respective zippyshare pages. On each page is a download button with actual direct link, but you need to click multiple times and see ads before being able to download.

What I am trying to do is essentially clicking the blue buttons and download the files, except with way more buttons and larger files.

The blue buttons are defined like this:

```
<button class="download" onclick="sZQlMJJhvnGLtjsdRRjGDRAmBGtyCrEUqvfdfPlAcSlwcEzTvJAZAbmbHGAjYfep/*1675699231*/('bVp9rzvGSmea8hU2fYqPN6WqkOLOYJtY1-dSbUYyp-8tkvPUliIEWKgpm2Wj2nkIJI3dVxfdKWOmDsvc3bsSL7R5zMfpUq7q54NU19SXlcCn4pa5UVWszZcQprjH7JXw', this);" target="_blank" title="Download" data-i18n="Download">
```

Suppose blue button is `button`, this mess is needed to get to zippyshare page:

```
'https://filecrypt.cc/Link/'+decodeURI(button.getAttribute('onclick').split("/(")[1].match(/(?<=').+(?=')/))+'.html'
```

On the zippyshare page use this to get download link:

```
document.evaluate('//a[@id="dlbutton"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.href
```

When I put them together they stopped working:

```js
var buttons = $x('//button[@class="download"]')
var links = []

for (let button of buttons) {
    let id = button.getAttribute('onclick').split("/(")[1].match(/(?<=').+(?=')/)
    let page = window.open('https://filecrypt.cc/Link/'+id+'.html')
    function f(){links.push(decodeURI(page.document.evaluate('//a[@id="dlbutton"]', page.document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.href)); page.close()}
    setTimeout(f, 1000)
}
```

I know JavaScript doesn't have a sleep function, and I can only find `setTimeOut` or `setInterval`, and neither of them work in a for loop, the execution isn't delayed at all.

`Links` is not updated. The tabs are not closed.

I got two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: page.document.evaluate(...).singleNodeValue is null
    f debugger eval code:7
    setTimeout handler* debugger eval code:8

Uncaught TypeError: page is null
    f debugger eval code:7
    setTimeout handler* debugger eval code:8
```

How can I make it work? I use Firefox and I can easily do it in Python Selenium but filecrypt blocked Selenium...

---

I rewrote my code and it still doesn't work:

```
var buttons = $x('//button[@class="download"]');
var links = [];
var i = 0;
                  
function getLink() {         
  setTimeout(function() {   
    let onclick = buttons[i].getAttribute('onclick')
    let jumbo = onclick.split("/(")[1].match(/(?<=').+(?=')/)
    let page = window.open(`https://filecrypt.cc/Link/${jumbo}.html`)
    let download = page.document.evaluate('//a[@id="dlbutton"]', page.document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
    let link = decodeURI(download.href)
    links.push(link)
    page.close()
    i++;                    
    if (i < buttons.length) {           
      getLink();             
    }                   
  }, 1000)
}

getLink();
```

Now it doesn't open all tabs at once, but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: download is null
    getLink debugger eval code:11
    setTimeout handler*getLink debugger eval code:6
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:21
```

Comment: please make a minimal reproducible example of it i am not very familiar with the service you are using